# is MS Velocity ready for production?

Tags: .net, appfabric, distributed-cache

I wonder if anyone has tried velocity in a production environment. It is in CTP2 version right now, and we are thinking of using it.  Has anyone tried it? If yes was it a positive experience?

Comment: Not to be confused with http://velocity.apache.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal take on this would be that you should use [Memcache](http://www.danga.com/memcached/) till [Velocity](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=B24C3708-EEFF-4055-A867-19B5851E7CD2&displaylang=en#Overview) stabilizes.  .net clients for Memcache like [Enyim](http://www.codeplex.com/EnyimMemcached) have stood the test of time and used by many.

- Use a provider independent
  CacheManager
- Implement one for memcached.
- Tomorrow if things change and you
  still want Velocity, change the
  provider.

After all, these are just dictionaries and your domain code should be independent of the infrastructure.

***Related***: [A simple CacheManager interface for C#](http://dotnetchris.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/critique-pluggable-aspnet-cachemanager/),
[My answer to Memcache on Windows.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351635/memcached-with-windows-and-c/352547#352547)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Velocity 1.0 has been released as a part of AppFabric. [You can download it from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=467e5aa5-c25b-4c80-a6d2-9f8fb0f337d2).

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping that the points I make here may help someone. We're in process of deploying AppFabric on our systems and have noticed a couple of things that need improvement:

- The documentation is outdated in most cases. You'll find details on certain blogs, but usually mixing and matching stuff from various sites will give you the details you need. Still not very happy with the standard of documentation.
- Troubleshooting is another issue. 90% of the times, you'll be dealing with install related issues. There are certain things that should've been documented from the get go to help trouble shooting, but never were thereby end up costing a lot more time getting it up and running than you might think.
- As far as the performance is concerned, I am almost certain that it isn't as fast as Memcached. Someone could prove me wrong, but until then, Memcached is the king of distributed caching.

Now here are some issues that I found a little troublesome:

- Dynamically adding/removing nodes
  to/from a cache cluster isn't as easy
  as they make it sound. I have read
  numerous complaints regarding the
  same on the forum. I haven't tried
  this yet, but you can read about it
  on the forums. There are some real
  issues.
- Throttling is another issue. In cases
  where the memory of the Lead Cache
  Cluster hits a high percent, the
  Caching just fails. This posed a
  tremendous problem for us since we
  were using the session provider and
  people started getting errors.

  Turns out, SQL Server and AppFabric
  shouldn't be put on the same box as
  SQL Server does tend to hog a lot of
  memory. What perplexes me is the fact
  that I had multiple nodes, but the
  Lead Cache had a memory issue and it
  didn't distribute it around. In my
  case, I only had one node and SQL
  Server and AppFabric were obviously
  on the same node due to the
  availability of a single server.
  Caching just fails in scenarios like
  these. If you have a backup running,
  you will notice that Caching will
  fail on that node because the memory
  usage on that box goes really high.

In my opinion, there are things with the product that make me feel like it was a little rushed. There are other products out there that we have previously used like ScaleOut that work much better until AppFabric matures.

Other than that, I think MSFT has done a decent enough job of providing us with something that can be used. Having something is better than having nothing, considering Memcached has provided such a great cutting-edge technology.