# What is the ASP.NET equivalent to memcached in PHP?

Tags: php, asp.net, memcached, code-behind

Is there an equivalent in ASP.NET to memcached usage in PHP? Is there even a way I could use memcached from the VB code behind, or something like it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Memcached](http://sourceforge.net/projects/memcacheddotnet/) works well with .net too, but equivalent would be [Velocity](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/velocity)

Answer (score 4):

That would be [Microsoft Velocity](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/velocity) which has now been rolled into [Windows Server AppFabric Caching](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/velocity/threads) It's not supported officially yet, but it's there. It's essentially (from what I can figure the same concept as Memcached. It's written as a native Windows Serivce, and you can use it as a state server for session. As an easy example of how it plugs nicely into Asp.Net

Also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351635/memcached-with-windows-and-net) for discussions on getting Memcached binding from C#.

**aside?**
You might also want to look at the all new and shiny NoSql stuff, depending on what you're trying to accomplish obviously. I'm currently playing with [RavenDb](http://github.com/ravendb/ravendb) but I'm not talking about running my enterprise on it... yet

Comment: Instead of using Memcache, could I use Microsoft AppFabric Caching for communication between PHP and ASP.NET? Will Microsoft AppFabric Caching work with PHP? If yes, how well does Microsoft AppFabric Caching work with PHP?

Answer (score 3):

memcached is a daemon, totally independant from PHP -- must be writtent in C/C++

It can be used from any language -- only condition is you'll need a library to communicate with it *(and there are some in lots of languages)*

For libraries, you can take a look at this page of memcached's wiki : [Clients](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/Clients).

Yes, it's often associated with PHP, but PHP is absolutly not a necessity -- I would say that association is often made for at least those reasons :

- Same technical background, at least at first : Linux
- Same philosophy : open source, free
- Easy inter-connection *(existence of libraries that are well-known)*
- Fits well with one of the most important idea of PHP : it's a glue language, that's great for inter-connecting distinct components, that are all great at what they do, and build an application using those.