# Distributed Key/Value Stores that can run on Windows, and have .Net clients?

Tags: .net, windows, persistence, nosql, key-value-store

As the title says, does anyone know of any Distributed Key/Value Stores that can run on Windows, and have .Net clients?

Thank you

Update: Sorry, forgot to add that it needs to be persisted.

Answer (score 1):

[App Fabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx) is Microsoft's solution.

[RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/) can probably act as a sophisticated key value store.

Additionally there are ports of [memcached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351635/memcached-with-windows-and-net) and [redis](https://github.com/rgl/redis) does work on windows.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry, I forgot to add that it needs the data needs to be persisted, so I guess memcached is out.  I had a quick look at Raven before, but was dissapointed at how much they are charging for commercial use - especially considering it is an unproven solution without an established user base.  Haven't looked at app fabric - will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MongoDB, CouchDB or Cassandra. They are more than a key-value-store but they do run on windows and have .net clients.

Answer (score 1):

[Membase](http://www.membase.com) is a distributed key-value store that supports Windows and has a .NET client (Enyim).

Answer (score 0):

[GetCache.net](http://www.getcache.net) is a distributed key/value store running on Windows and has .Net client library. It works only in-memory.