# Ideas for a single machine, cross process object cache?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, caching

I've got a solution (.net 4, c#) consisting of a webapplication, several windows forms apps and a couple of windows services. Now I'd like to implement a global caching mechanism, so that all these application access the same cache (if possible with as little changes to existing code). My first guess would be using a AOP for implementing the cache and a WCF host on the machine for storing the values. Is that a good way to go? Do you have other suggestions, links, how-to's? Thanks in advance!

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563678/distributed-key-value-stores-that-can-run-on-windows-and-have-net-clients/3563705#3563705

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Memcached](http://sourceforge.net/projects/memcacheddotnet/) for .net