# Is an overkill using App Fabric only for caching?

Tags: .net, asp.net, memcached, appfabric

We're evaluating different options for distributed cache. I have some experience with memcached but no experience with Velocity (App Fabric cache services).

I wonder if using App Fabric only for distributed caching make no sense taking into account that there are very mature tools as memcached specially designed for this purpose.

Comment: I personally prefer memcached, but using AppFabric just for caching is fine if that's the cache provider you prefer.

Comment: mabye have a read of this discussion : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351635/memcached-with-windows-and-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you own the infrastructure and plan to continue owning the infrastructure for you application, then supporting the tool of familiarity makes sense. If you have the ability to manage a heterogeneous environment for the life of your application (say 5-10 years) stick with memcached. If you think you are going to deploy into Windows Azure, then you will only have App Fabric as an option.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used memcached so I'm not sure how it compares, but I've used App Fabric for distributed session state caching in an ASP.NET web application. It was pretty easy to set up and has been pretty reliable as well.